# Creating a pop out menu without a nav bar button

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to create a pop out menu in my app just like the facebook app uses.

I found this really good tutorial and got it working in their example. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

In their example, they use a nav bar item on a nav bar as the button that activates and deactivates the pop out menu.

In my current project, I don't want to use a nav bar and would prefer to just have a button that activates the pop out menu.

I don't what do when it comes to the following piece of code though.

```
// Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
_sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

// Set the gesture
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

I can't set actions and targets to a normal button.

Is there any easy way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using iPhone or iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a UIButton to call a selector like this:

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(revealToggle:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put this code in your button action:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo",@"Choose Existing", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

This view will come up from the bottom of the screen:

[image: UIActionSheet]

Comment: A bit different compared to the style I was going for but a good approach, going to keep this in mind.

Comment: Can you please give me +1?